# Way to show wide table neatly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a basic screen which simply shows a grid of data, but the grid can have more columns than the screen can cope with. I plan to use Bootstrap, but just for it's controls, look and feel. The page, however, does not need to scale for mobile.

A very basic example of the data I am showing looks like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/bunwt5cy/1/

So, first column is just an incrementing number, followed by a date, and then the data. The number of columns can range from 1 account, to 20. Each column (cell) then has 3 financial values (2 shown in demo) ranging from 0.00 to 99,999.99 (To show sizes required).

I'm currently using `<TABLE>`, but is there a better way, using bootstrap, to do this? Can it be done better with DIVs? And if I do, am I limited to 12 Divs per row? If so, that's not an option then, as my grid may have > 12 columns.

Here is an example of some rows. I'm trying to make it neater, and use 'as best as possible' best practice, but also, make pretty.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice, you should continue to use `table` element for such spreadsheet-like, tabular data, while using CSS to make it "pretty".

The [div element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) according to the HTML5 specs:

> The div element has no special meaning at all ...
>
> Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable. Use of more appropriate elements instead of the div element leads to better accessibility for readers and easier maintainability for authors.

In this case `table` is available, it is appropriate for tabular data, so in terms of best practice, you should continue using `table` element for such tabular data rather than `div`.

Comment: Thanks for that! And then just to confirm, within a cell (A cell, in my case, represents a date, and an account), there is 3 values to be displayed. Is it right/OK to use a table, within a table for formatting? Problem here could be that alignment of the cell above's table might go wrong, when the 'length' of the values differ...

Comment: Good question, no I wouldn't do that kind of nesting of tables if presenting tabular data, none of the HTML5 table examples have nesting. Could look at making use of `scope=` attribute, if you have say Account1 as a column heading and at least as sub-columns of Account1. The HTML5 spec link posted, on same page, has an example with cats but its using `scope=rowgroup` for your case you'd probably be interested in doing similar but using `scope=colgroup`, to group columns, not rows.